# Make exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

I want to test development code. How I can make exception into my code in order to test code?

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: sorry could not understand what you want to do

Comment: This code works, even if it's not advise to throw `Exception` since it's too generic.

Comment: you do catch the exception which is thrown, but you don't do anything in the catch block, so it'll be hidden for you.
add e.printStackTrace(); in the catch block

Comment: Try to choose a correct answer when you put a question. It will help others to understand the status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should throw the exception from your function. If you use try with a catch block it will catch it and not throwing it. So try like this,

sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("My stuff");

    throw new Exception();      

}
```

Output :

```
My stuff
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception
    at Check.main(Check.java:16)
```

Actually if you are using eclipse when you add the line  `throw new Exception();` it will give you 2 solution, 1. try catch 2. throws then , use **throws**

Answer (score 0):

You can learn the bases of Java Exceptions here : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm